# How to restart service by PID on windows

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to restart a lot of services on windows servers, but I just know their PID.
How to use PowerShell to restart all services by their PID?

I saw the official document just the command below

```
Restart-Service
       [-Force]
       [-Name] <String[]>
       [-PassThru]
       [-Include <String[]>]
       [-Exclude <String[]>]
       [-WhatIf]
       [-Confirm]
       [<CommonParameters>]
```

Comment: You can get the service name from the PID like this: `(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Service -Filter "ProcessId='$PID'").Name` (where variable `$PID` contains the ProcessId)

Comment: This is not possible in general because a single process may be hosting multiple services -- there is a one-to-many mapping. You can, of course, restart all services hosted in a process, but that may not be what you want. You'll need the `Win32_Service` WMI object for this, as `Get-Service` doesn't expose the PID (i.e. `Get-WmiObject Win32_Service |? { $myprocessids -contains $_.ProcessId } | Restart-Service`).

Answer (score -1):

Example:

```
$p = "4836"
Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Service -Filter "ProcessId LIKE '$($p)'"
Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Service -Filter "ProcessId LIKE '$($p)'" | %{Restart-Service -Name $_.Name}
```

[Get-CimInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: This will bring down all other services running at that PID as well - Not just the one you'd like to restart :/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).